# Passing an array value from one class to another

Tags: java, arrays

I want all my array data from this class to be passed to another class and I don't know how to do it.
Here is my code:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String menu[] = {"", "Hotsilog", "Porksilog",
            "Bangsilog", "Tapsilog", "Chicksilog"};
    double priceList[] = {0, 20.00, 20.00, 20.00, 20.00, 20.00};
    int quantOrder[] = new int[100];
    int foodChoice[] = new int[100];
    int qntty = 0;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.printf("      %3s%14s\n", "Menu", "Price");
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        System.out.printf("[%d] %-15s%.2f\n", i, menu[i], priceList[i]);
    }
    System.out.print("How many items do you want to order? ");
    qntty = scan.nextInt();
    for (int i = 1; i <= qntty; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter the number of your choice: ");
        foodChoice[i] = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("You choose " + menu[foodChoice[i]] + "!");
        System.out.print("Quantity of order :");
        quantOrder[i] = scan.nextInt();
    }
}
```

And I want all the datas from up there to be passed to this class and compute all the prices

```java
public class methOds {
    double Price[] = new double[100];
    double totalPrice = 0;

    methOds() {
        Price[i] = priceList[foodChoice[i]] * quantOrder[i];
        totalPrice = totalPrice + Price[i];
    }
}
```

Can some explain me how to work with it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize the pricelist and quantity ordered arrays to the method class and that you can pass into the constructor.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String menu[] = {"", "Hotsilog", "Porksilog",
            "Bangsilog", "Tapsilog", "Chicksilog"};
    double priceList[] = {0, 20.00, 20.00, 20.00, 20.00, 20.00};
    int quantOrder[] = new int[100];
    int foodChoice[] = new int[100];
    int qntty = 0;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.printf("      %3s%14s\n", "Menu", "Price");
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        System.out.printf("[%d] %-15s%.2f\n", i, menu[i], priceList[i]);
    }
    System.out.print("How many items do you want to order? ");
    qntty = scan.nextInt();
    for (int i = 1; i <= qntty; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter the number of your choice: ");
        foodChoice[i] = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("You choose " + menu[foodChoice[i]] + "!");
        System.out.print("Quantity of order :");
        quantOrder[i] = scan.nextInt();
    }
    methOds method_obj = new methOds(priceList, quantOrder);
    System.out.println(method_obj.totalPrice());
}
```

Modify your constructor and make it a parametrized one by passing both the quantOrder and foodChoice arrays so that the values could be calculated in the
totalPrice method.

```java
public class methOds {
    private double Price[] = new double[100];
    private double totalPrice = 0;
    private int quantOrder[];
    private int foodChoice[];

    public methOds(quantOrder, foodChoice) {
        this.quantOrder = quantOrder;
        this.foodChoice = foodChoice;
    }

    public int totalPrice() {
        //Method to calculate the total price
        for (int i; i < Price.length; i++) {
            Price[i] = priceList[foodChoice[i]] * quantOrder[i];
            totalPrice = totalPrice + Price[i];
        }
        return totalPrice;
    }
}
```